# How do i implement the knockout if and ifnot binding to hide and display web elements such as divs and other tags

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm, knockout.js

I am using knockout and I am trying to hide or display two buttons based on the a value of a boolean that I have named server but I am not quite getting it right. Below is the code that I have come up with so far please assist I think there is something missing in my syntax

```
 <!-- ko if: server  -->
<a class="btn btn-small" data-bind="css: { 'device-action-on': status(), 'device-action-off': !status() }, click: $root.deviceMetricsVM.toggleSensorState">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> </a>


<a class="btn btn-small" data-bind="css: { 'device-action-on': mode(), 'device-action-off': !mode() }, click: $root.deviceMetricsVM.toggleHomeMode">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
  </a>
<!-- /ko-->

<!-- ko ifnot: server  -->
<a class="btn btn-small" data-bind="css: { 'device-action-on': status(), 'device-action-off': !status() }, click: $root.deviceMetricsVM.toggleSensorState" style="display:none;">
<i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
 </a>

<a class="btn btn-small" data-bind="css: { 'device-action-on': mode(), 'device-action-off': !mode() }, click: $root.deviceMetricsVM.toggleHomeMode" style="display:none;">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
</a>
 <!-- /ko-->
```

Comment: Your `<a>` don't have an `href` url.  And the `<i>` don't have any text.  In the `ifnot` the `<a>` have `style="display:none;"`.  At least add text inside the `<i>` and remove the `style="display:none;"`.  Here is a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/9bp4dzwe/1/.

Comment: What is the error/problem when you try to render the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I would display the value of server to the UI to make sure it's the value you think it is. It might be that "server" is out of scope for that particular HTML.

Put this at the top of the HTML and see what happens.

```
<span>Server value: </span>
<span data-bind="text: server"></span>
```

Make sure to check your browser JavaScript console output for clues and errors.